# Correction of the json file

Tags: python, json

Faced with an interesting problem, there is a json file in which, instead of, 'used ', is there any way to replace all 'with ' using Python or just do it manually using control F?

Пытался использовать следующий код, но он не сработал:

```
import json

with open('first_task.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

json_str = json.dumps(data).replace("'", '"')

with open('first_task.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_str)
```

Comment: If it uses `'` instead of `"` it's not a JSON file. You should contact the creator of the file and tell them to do it properly. There's no reliable way to fix it, because you need to distinguish the quotes that are used to delimit strings (which should be replaced) with quotes that are inside strings (which should be left alone).

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to describe the problem correctly. You have single quotes in both places.

Comment: If you're going to do the replacement, you have to do it BEFORE you try to load the JSON. `data = json.loads(f.read().replace("'", '"'))`

Comment: @Barmar , but is there still a way ? If, for example, we are sure that ' is not used in words inside the file?

Comment: See my last comment

Comment: @Barmar I did as you recommended, the following code turned out:
 ```import json


with open('testing.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read().replace("'", '"'))
    data2=str(data)


with open('testing.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data2)```
But the file remains unchanged

Comment: @AndreyBaev, if that doesn't work, run the code in a debugger to inspect it in every single stage. Your question also lacks a [mcve], including the input data (preferably hardcoded into the Python code) and the expected output data. You can [edit] your question to clarify that, including the mix-up of single and double quotes there. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If the file uses single quotes instead of double quotes, it might be python format, so you could use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

As said before by the commentators of question, you need to prepare data before convert to json object.
If you want to fix json file there is way you can do it.

```py
import json

# Fix json file
with open('first_task.json', 'r') as f:
    raw_data = f.read()  # READING FILE TO STRING
    json_str = raw_data.replace("'", "\"")  # FIXED JSON STRING

data_json = json.loads(json_str)  # JSON OBJECT

with open('first_task_fixed.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data_json, f)  # SAVING FIXED JSON FILE
```

Example:

```json
{
    'data': {
        'val_1': true,
        'val_2': false
    }
}
```

Example output:

```json
{"data": {"val_1": true, "val_2": false}}
```